Modal greys background but does not appear (website becomes unresponsive)
I am new to web development and I have ran into an issue when working with modals. I require a modal to be activated by a button that appears to be a link from within an accordion. The button will link to a contact us form allowing the user to pose any questions they may have. The problem is when the button is pressed the background greys but no modal appears and the website crashes.
Please point me in the right direction...
This is the code used....
 <!-- Item 5 -->
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header">
            <button
              class="accordion-button collapsed"
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#question-five"
            >
              Still have a question?
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div
            id="question-five"
            class="accordion-collapse collapse"
            data-bs-parent="#questions"
          >
            <div class="accordion-body">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <p> <br> 
             <button
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#contact"  
                type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Modal for contact form -->
    <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="contact"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="contactLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="contactLabel">Contact Us!</h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          > </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p class="lead">Fill out the following fields!</p>
          <form>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="first-name" class="col-form-label">
               Full Name:
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email Address:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="message" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="message" />
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>



HTML5 offers a modal system using the <dialog> tag with the js .showModal() method in which you can still use Boostrap CSS. Simpler and more reliable to use than B5's JS/CSS machinery. (and use CSS ::backdrop )
